# WriteRaster in a loop for several rasters while assigning unique band names

Tags: raster, r

I have a series of raster stacks representing median and maximum composite images in a 35-year time series. Each stack has five bands: NDVI, NBR, brightness, greenness, wetness. I need to convert them from .grd to .tif on a band by band basis and label each band with the appropriate name and year (ex: Med_2001_NDVI).

In the past I've used this code to export stacks by band. It works well and assigns the correct band names, but can only process one raster at a time.

```
namesb<-c("NDVI_13med"," NBR_13med", "Bright_13med", "Green_13med", "Wet_13med")
for(i in seq_along(s13med)){writeRaster(s13med[[i]], file=namesb[i], format="GTiff")}
```

I would like to modify it to read every raster in the folder then `writeRaster` by layer with the correct names assigned. This is my preliminary code. I'm unsure how to name them appropriately.

```
a<-list.files(pattern="*.grd$")
b<-lapply(a, stack)
year<-substr(a, 1, 8)
bands<-c("NDVI","NBR","Brightness","Greenness", "Wetness")
for(i in seq_along(b)){writeRaster(b[[i]], file=(???), bylayer=T, format="GTiff")}
```

The final name for each band needs to be a combination of "year" and the appropriate band name from "bands". The name format doesn't need to exactly match my 2013 example. I just need to know the band name, the year, and whether it's a median or maximum composite image.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do that like this:

```
a <- list.files(pattern="\\.grd$")
b <- lapply(a, stack)
year <- substr(a, 1, 8)
bands <- c("NDVI","NBR","Brightness","Greenness", "Wetness")

fnames <- lapply(year, function(y) paste0(bands, "_", y, ".tif"))


for(i in seq_along(b)){
    writeRaster(b[[i]], filename=fnames[[i]], bylayer=TRUE)
}
```